# How do I scrape the data only for a specific year and month?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the review identifier and review date in MDY format (e.g. January 6, 2018) from trip advisor website. Since there are a lot of reviews even for one hotel, I'm trying to scrape the review data within a certain period of time only. Let's say that period of time ranges from June 2017 to December 2017, how do I sort out the corresponding data? The simplest thing I can think of is I scrape all the reviews for a hotel and then filter out what I want later. But the website is not letting me to scrape all the reviews (sometimes getting blocked). So my plan is to scrape only that portion of the reviews while not getting blocked. Could anyone have a good idea on how to scrape the data within June 2017 - December 2017?
Here's my current code. This gives 2 variables (review id, review date) with 5 observations that ranged from Dec 2017 to Jan 2018.

```
import datetime
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

listed_reviews_total=[]

#an example page where there are 5 reviews. I had multiple elements but showed you only one to be simple.
listing_url=["https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g155032-d12237304-Reviews-or155-Holiday_Inn_Hotel_Suites_Montreal_Centre_ville_Ouest-Montreal_Quebec.html"]

for k in listing_url:
    page=urlopen(k)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")    
    time.sleep(3)
    listing=soup.findAll("div",{"class":"review-container"})
    for i in range(len(listing)):
            review_id=listing[i]["data-reviewid"]
            listing_v1=soup.findAll("div", {"class":"prw_rup prw_reviews_review_resp"})
            review_date=listing_v1[i].find("span",{"class":"ratingDate"})
            review_date_detail=review_date["title"]
            listed_reviews=[review_id, review_date_detail]
            listed_reviews.extend([k])
            listed_reviews_total.append(listed_reviews)
    print (len(listed_reviews_total))
    print (listed_reviews_total)
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import time
import csv

#There are actually more than two but to put it simple.
listing_url=["https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g155032-d12237304-Reviews-Holiday_Inn_Hotel_Suites_Montreal_Centre_ville_Ouest-Montreal_Quebec.html","https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g155032-d155205-Reviews-Comfort_Suites_Downtown-Montreal_Quebec.html"]


for k in listing_url:
    data = 'changeSet=REVIEW_LIST'
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'cookie': 'VRMCID=%1%V1*id.10568*llp.%2F*e.1560821283491; TAUnique=%1%enc%3AlDqra346CYNe2oFFOebaM2LiS5PSM6Dpd5ss7m1Idn8%3D; CM=%1%PremiumMobSess%2C%2C-1%7Ct4b-pc%2C%2C-1%7CRestAds%2FRPers%2C%2C-1%7CRCPers%2C%2C-1%7CWShadeSeen%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkMCCPers%2C%2C-1%7CHomeASess%2C2%2C-1%7CPremiumSURPers%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumMCSess%2C%2C-1%7CRestPartSess%2C%2C-1%7CRestPremRSess%2C%2C-1%7CCCSess%2C%2C-1%7CCYLSess%2C%2C-1%7CViatorMCPers%2C%2C-1%7Csesssticker%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumORSess%2C%2C-1%7Ct4b-sc%2C%2C-1%7CRestAdsPers%2C%2C-1%7CMC_IB_UPSELL_IB_LOGOS2%2C%2C-1%7Cb2bmcpers%2C%2C-1%7CPremMCBtmSess%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumSURSess%2C%2C-1%7CMC_IB_UPSELL_IB_LOGOS%2C%2C-1%7CLaFourchette+Banners%2C%2C-1%7Csess_rev%2C%2C-1%7Csessamex%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumRRSess%2C%2C-1%7CTADORSess%2C%2C-1%7CTARSWBPers%2C%2C-1%7CSPMCSess%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkORSess%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkRRSess%2C%2C-1%7Cpers_rev%2C%2C-1%7CSPMCWBPers%2C%2C-1%7CRBAPers%2C%2C-1%7CRestAds%2FRSess%2C%2C-1%7CHomeAPers%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumMobPers%2C%2C-1%7CRCSess%2C%2C-1%7CLaFourchette+MC+Banners%2C%2C-1%7CRestAdsCCSess%2C%2C-1%7CRestPartPers%2C%2C-1%7CRestPremRPers%2C%2C-1%7Csh%2C%2C-1%7Cpssamex%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkMCCSess%2C%2C-1%7CCYLPers%2C%2C-1%7CCCPers%2C%2C-1%7Cb2bmcsess%2C%2C-1%7CSPMCPers%2C%2C-1%7CViatorMCSess%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumMCPers%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumRRPers%2C%2C-1%7CRestAdsCCPers%2C%2C-1%7CTADORPers%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkORPers%2C%2C-1%7CPremMCBtmPers%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkRRPers%2C%2C-1%7CTARSWBSess%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumORPers%2C%2C-1%7CRestAdsSess%2C%2C-1%7CRBASess%2C%2C-1%7CSPORPers%2C%2C-1%7Cperssticker%2C%2C-1%7CSPMCWBSess%2C%2C-1%7C; __gads=ID=80b73b494251f08f:T=1560216487:S=ALNI_MYxdo3gOkPGrsxb9kGdERgOvL-biw; TASSK=enc%3AAM85QGP7TErhmUIO9mM5yPlJa4z6Jx3T9zTXeFwj5yaDuxT1RvDvGCemE70Jbw5%2BtIBDquAnUNZ2m5VLGuuvRtGmkCtlMC1OW7e6AVSbk0xUPC7TnSsaw1U8FhrBl8t3%2BQ%3D%3D; BEPIN=%1%16ccacac52e%3Bbak207b.b.tripadvisor.com%3A10023%3B; ServerPool=T; PMC=V2*MS.3*MD.20190825*LD.20190825; TATravelInfo=V2*AY.2019*AM.9*AD.8*DY.2019*DM.9*DD.9*A.2*MG.-1*HP.2*FL.3*DSM.1566770382318*RS.1; TART=%1%enc%3AXtqBRTnm2jNrsrMi2CxcSuIYVpKWXuXqDscF5AFmxraBqxqvS4TTNL4xNEA4Fg2JNox8JbUSTxk%3D; PAC=AKI0Ak_wHxo1xVz2A_kIgU8afLzDybZKx16rKbTcC2dAWYfbE4f9VQqDxKMvap6yTTyaWhGH6TJKElQ-o5EQK6vSAux0awkZyssfXcMSzr_a4yoU-UxjSjh8VBCKr6rPgjUZapUSxllTx7dNRbU1KKzkv83-AR7D1uYIPHYGswVCierahneqD1HvcFWMn8_nzA%3D%3D; TAReturnTo=%1%%2FHotel_Review-g155032-d12237304-Reviews-Holiday_Inn_Hotel_Suites_Montreal_Centre_ville_Ouest-Montreal_Quebec.html; roybatty=TNI1625!ADHt%2BO1VDwozzKEvwcyfZrPDM9h5c5NXZX4eLIkKd6GrgAeBXdyPbE0DqaM%2FNvGtkS%2Fzr3yXhUr4R7rO%2FBLS6BU6%2FG9N2prFQs0s17Om2OPfFGHsV5JqdMlv6W2ykScrBajEJA%2FCnEcL01PxPoAfVCDgxWWLTtXSl2a18k6Bxl12%2C1; SRT=%1%enc%3AXtqBRTnm2jNrsrMi2CxcSuIYVpKWXuXqDscF5AFmxraBqxqvS4TTNL4xNEA4Fg2JNox8JbUSTxk%3D; TASession=V2ID.6F7A576FFF33B3D5E31756EE43C2D7AC*SQ.50*LS.PageMoniker*GR.75*TCPAR.95*TBR.16*EXEX.87*ABTR.83*PHTB.24*FS.84*CPU.94*HS.recommended*ES.popularity*DS.5*SAS.popularity*FPS.oldFirst*LF.en*FA.1*DF.0*TRA.false*LD.12237304; TAUD=LA-1566770383428-1*RDD-1-2019_08_25*HDD-1-2019_09_08.2019_09_09.1*LD-9055362-2019.9.8.2019.9.9*LG-9055364-2.1.F.',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }

    #Date ranges for reviews
    start = datetime.date(2019, 7, 1)
    end = datetime.date(2019, 8, 25)

    s = requests.Session()
    #s.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g155032-d12237304-Reviews-Holiday_Inn_Hotel_Suites_Montreal_Centre_ville_Ouest-Montreal_Quebec.html')
    s.get(k)

    listed_reviews_total = []
    for next_num in range(0, 25, 5):

        url_1='-'.join(k.split('-',4)[:4])
        url_2='-'.join(k.split('-',4)[4:])
        middle="-or{%d}-" % next_num
        final_k=url_1+middle+url_2

    #r = s.post(f"https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g155032-d12237304-Reviews-or{next_num}-Holiday_Inn_Hotel_Suites_Montreal_Centre_ville_Ouest-Montreal_Quebec.html", data=data, headers=headers)
    #r= s.post(f"https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g155032-d155205-Reviews-or{next_num}-Comfort_Suites_Downtown-Montreal_Quebec.html", data=data, headers=headers)
        r= s.post(final_k, data=data, headers=headers)

        #Try to parse again in case that it didn't work properly.
        for try_again in range(0,10,1):    

            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            time.sleep(4)
            listing=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"review-container"})

            if len(listing)==0:
                print ("fail")
                continue
            elif len(listing)!=0:
                print ("success")
                break


        for review in listing:
            review_id=review["data-reviewid"]
            listing_v1=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"prw_rup prw_reviews_review_resp"})
            review_date=review.find("span",{"class":"ratingDate"})
            review_date_detail=review_date["title"]
            date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(review_date_detail, '%B %d, %Y').date()
            if end-date_obj> datetime.timedelta(0) and date_obj-start>datetime.timedelta(0): #Checks if review is within specific date
                listed_reviews=[review_id, review_date_detail]
                listed_reviews.extend([k])
                listed_reviews_total.append(listed_reviews)


print(len(listed_reviews_total))
print(listed_reviews_total)


#Export 'listed_reviews_total' (each list will be at each row) to CSV directly (header included).
with open("trip_advisor_reviews_stack_overflow_v3.csv","w") as output:
    csv_out = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    #csv_out.writerow(['review_id','review_date','rating','listing_url'])
    csv_out.writerow(['review_id','review_date','listing_url']) 
    for row in listed_reviews_total:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I used to look at all the reviews at this hotel is with the requests library. The url changes slightly every time you look at the next set of 5 reviews. I was able grab the ID and dates of all the reviews, but I still added the date functionality to sort out the corresponding data.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

data = 'changeSet=REVIEW_LIST'
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'cookie': 'VRMCID=%1%V1*id.10568*llp.%2F*e.1560821283491; TAUnique=%1%enc%3AlDqra346CYNe2oFFOebaM2LiS5PSM6Dpd5ss7m1Idn8%3D; CM=%1%PremiumMobSess%2C%2C-1%7Ct4b-pc%2C%2C-1%7CRestAds%2FRPers%2C%2C-1%7CRCPers%2C%2C-1%7CWShadeSeen%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkMCCPers%2C%2C-1%7CHomeASess%2C2%2C-1%7CPremiumSURPers%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumMCSess%2C%2C-1%7CRestPartSess%2C%2C-1%7CRestPremRSess%2C%2C-1%7CCCSess%2C%2C-1%7CCYLSess%2C%2C-1%7CViatorMCPers%2C%2C-1%7Csesssticker%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumORSess%2C%2C-1%7Ct4b-sc%2C%2C-1%7CRestAdsPers%2C%2C-1%7CMC_IB_UPSELL_IB_LOGOS2%2C%2C-1%7Cb2bmcpers%2C%2C-1%7CPremMCBtmSess%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumSURSess%2C%2C-1%7CMC_IB_UPSELL_IB_LOGOS%2C%2C-1%7CLaFourchette+Banners%2C%2C-1%7Csess_rev%2C%2C-1%7Csessamex%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumRRSess%2C%2C-1%7CTADORSess%2C%2C-1%7CTARSWBPers%2C%2C-1%7CSPMCSess%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkORSess%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkRRSess%2C%2C-1%7Cpers_rev%2C%2C-1%7CSPMCWBPers%2C%2C-1%7CRBAPers%2C%2C-1%7CRestAds%2FRSess%2C%2C-1%7CHomeAPers%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumMobPers%2C%2C-1%7CRCSess%2C%2C-1%7CLaFourchette+MC+Banners%2C%2C-1%7CRestAdsCCSess%2C%2C-1%7CRestPartPers%2C%2C-1%7CRestPremRPers%2C%2C-1%7Csh%2C%2C-1%7Cpssamex%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkMCCSess%2C%2C-1%7CCYLPers%2C%2C-1%7CCCPers%2C%2C-1%7Cb2bmcsess%2C%2C-1%7CSPMCPers%2C%2C-1%7CViatorMCSess%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumMCPers%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumRRPers%2C%2C-1%7CRestAdsCCPers%2C%2C-1%7CTADORPers%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkORPers%2C%2C-1%7CPremMCBtmPers%2C%2C-1%7CTheForkRRPers%2C%2C-1%7CTARSWBSess%2C%2C-1%7CPremiumORPers%2C%2C-1%7CRestAdsSess%2C%2C-1%7CRBASess%2C%2C-1%7CSPORPers%2C%2C-1%7Cperssticker%2C%2C-1%7CSPMCWBSess%2C%2C-1%7C; __gads=ID=80b73b494251f08f:T=1560216487:S=ALNI_MYxdo3gOkPGrsxb9kGdERgOvL-biw; TASSK=enc%3AAM85QGP7TErhmUIO9mM5yPlJa4z6Jx3T9zTXeFwj5yaDuxT1RvDvGCemE70Jbw5%2BtIBDquAnUNZ2m5VLGuuvRtGmkCtlMC1OW7e6AVSbk0xUPC7TnSsaw1U8FhrBl8t3%2BQ%3D%3D; BEPIN=%1%16ccacac52e%3Bbak207b.b.tripadvisor.com%3A10023%3B; ServerPool=T; PMC=V2*MS.3*MD.20190825*LD.20190825; TATravelInfo=V2*AY.2019*AM.9*AD.8*DY.2019*DM.9*DD.9*A.2*MG.-1*HP.2*FL.3*DSM.1566770382318*RS.1; TART=%1%enc%3AXtqBRTnm2jNrsrMi2CxcSuIYVpKWXuXqDscF5AFmxraBqxqvS4TTNL4xNEA4Fg2JNox8JbUSTxk%3D; PAC=AKI0Ak_wHxo1xVz2A_kIgU8afLzDybZKx16rKbTcC2dAWYfbE4f9VQqDxKMvap6yTTyaWhGH6TJKElQ-o5EQK6vSAux0awkZyssfXcMSzr_a4yoU-UxjSjh8VBCKr6rPgjUZapUSxllTx7dNRbU1KKzkv83-AR7D1uYIPHYGswVCierahneqD1HvcFWMn8_nzA%3D%3D; TAReturnTo=%1%%2FHotel_Review-g155032-d12237304-Reviews-Holiday_Inn_Hotel_Suites_Montreal_Centre_ville_Ouest-Montreal_Quebec.html; roybatty=TNI1625!ADHt%2BO1VDwozzKEvwcyfZrPDM9h5c5NXZX4eLIkKd6GrgAeBXdyPbE0DqaM%2FNvGtkS%2Fzr3yXhUr4R7rO%2FBLS6BU6%2FG9N2prFQs0s17Om2OPfFGHsV5JqdMlv6W2ykScrBajEJA%2FCnEcL01PxPoAfVCDgxWWLTtXSl2a18k6Bxl12%2C1; SRT=%1%enc%3AXtqBRTnm2jNrsrMi2CxcSuIYVpKWXuXqDscF5AFmxraBqxqvS4TTNL4xNEA4Fg2JNox8JbUSTxk%3D; TASession=V2ID.6F7A576FFF33B3D5E31756EE43C2D7AC*SQ.50*LS.PageMoniker*GR.75*TCPAR.95*TBR.16*EXEX.87*ABTR.83*PHTB.24*FS.84*CPU.94*HS.recommended*ES.popularity*DS.5*SAS.popularity*FPS.oldFirst*LF.en*FA.1*DF.0*TRA.false*LD.12237304; TAUD=LA-1566770383428-1*RDD-1-2019_08_25*HDD-1-2019_09_08.2019_09_09.1*LD-9055362-2019.9.8.2019.9.9*LG-9055364-2.1.F.',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

#Date ranges for reviews
start = datetime.date(2017, 6, 1)
end = datetime.date(2017, 12, 31)

s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g155032-d12237304-Reviews-Holiday_Inn_Hotel_Suites_Montreal_Centre_ville_Ouest-Montreal_Quebec.html')

listed_reviews_total = []
for next_num in range(0, 211, 5):
    r = s.post(f"https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g155032-d12237304-Reviews-or{next_num}-Holiday_Inn_Hotel_Suites_Montreal_Centre_ville_Ouest-Montreal_Quebec.html", data=data, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    listing=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"review-container"})
    for review in listing:
        review_id=review["data-reviewid"]
        listing_v1=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"prw_rup prw_reviews_review_resp"})
        review_date=review.find("span",{"class":"ratingDate"})
        review_date_detail=review_date["title"]
        date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(review_date_detail, '%B %d, %Y').date()
        if end-date_obj> datetime.timedelta(0) and date_obj-start>datetime.timedelta(0): #Checks if review is within specific date
            listed_reviews_total.append([review_id, review_date_detail])


print(len(listed_reviews_total))
print(listed_reviews_total)
```

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your answers. Your code is at an another level compared to mine. Because I used to get blocked (couldn't scrape all the reviews). Yours perfectly scrape what I want. Like you mentioned, I also noticed that url changes as I move to the next page (-or5- part). I tried to change the url by splitting it and adding that part in the middle and then tried to loop over those adjusted urls but kept failing to scrape the reviews.

Comment: Once again, thank you. You're saving my life. I've been struggling with this for a few days. If you don't mind, may I ask what is the meaning of the inside of the headers? I tried to loop your code over the other hotels so that I can get other reviews for other hotels as well. Should I change the inner part of the header if I loop over the other hotels?

Comment: Whenever your browser requests a website, your browser sends headers to the server. Those aren't all the headers the script sends to the tripadvisor server but they're the ones that I needed to change to get the actual html of the website. I think the cookie header value is the only one that might need to change for other hotels to work.

Comment: The way to get this value (if necessary) is go to the hotel website, open up "inspect element" (I use chrome), and switch to the Network tab. Then, clear everything logged if there are requests there ("Do Not" icon), go to the review section of the hotel, and click the Next button. Now filter these requests by XHR in the network tab. If you don't see the filter options, you need to click the filter icon first. Click on the request that says Hotel_Review....something something. Scroll down to the Request Headers section and look for the cookie. If you need help with something, you can ask.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found where cookies are. Those seem to have different values from hotel to hotel. Now I realized that why I couldn't scrape the reviews from other hotels even though I tried to loop your code over the other hotels. If I have to loop over multiple hotels, how can I get each cookie header value for each hotel more efficiently?

Comment: For you convinience, I just added a few lines of codes based on yours. I was trying to loop over multiple hotels to get the reviews from multiple hotels.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to gather these cookies with automation. I'll look into it. I can see how this would be a problem if you have a lot of hotel links.

Comment: I found another way to go about it, but this method hasn't been 100% for me. For some hotels, I had to run it twice for it to work. Look at my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the headers with:

```
'authority': 'www.tripadvisor.com',
'method': 'POST',
'scheme': 'https',
'accept': 'text/html, */*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'content-length': '102',
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'origin': 'https://www.tripadvisor.com',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
```

---

And replace the data with:

reqNum=1&isLastPoll=false&paramSeqId=0&waitTime=11&changeSet=REVIEW_LIST&puid=XWRRSAoQIkQAAkl1JdoAAAFI

---

The other option is to manually find the cookie for each hotel.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just replaced the headers and data as you told me but the code doesn't loop over those two hotels. Maybe I'm missing something in my code?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot that I needed to also change the cookie for each hotel.

Comment: This answer was to try and avoid using cookies because I don't think there is a way to efficiently retrieve the cookie value other than doing it manually. If this did not work then just disregard this answer. I can't help with getting the cookie value more efficiently.

Comment: I found out that it doesn't work without cookie key and value pairs. Hmmm, I was searching for how to get the cookie value from each hotel and make it as a list or dic to simultaneously loop over. Like you said, it would be easy. But I really appreciate your help. Thank you.